# Bound of inf of finite Dirichlet series $\sum e^{i\alpha_j t}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, dirichlet-series

In a short note by S. Rudolfer and W.K. Hayman (1980), there is a sketch of a proof for an upper bound of $\mu =\inf |P(t)|$ where $$P(t) = \sum_{j=1}^n e^{i\alpha_j t}$$ and $\alpha_j \neq \alpha_k$ for $j\neq k$.  There are a couple points of the argument that I can't puzzle through.  They assert that $\mu \leq \sqrt{n-1}.$

Here is the argument:  Note that $|P(t)|^2 = n + 2\sum_{j\neq k} \cos((\alpha_j-\alpha_k)t).$   If $w(t) = |P|^2-n \geq -c$, then let

$$h(t) = c+w(t) = 2\sum b_k \cos \delta_k t$$

where the $b_k$ are positive integers.  (No limits indicated on this last summation.)  Then

$$b_k = \lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T} h(t)\cos(\delta_k t) \; dt \leq \lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T} h(t) \; dt = c.$$

They conclude that $c\geq 1$.

My first problem is, "What are the $\delta_k$'s?  At first I thought they were just the collection of the various $(\alpha_j -\alpha_k)$'s but now I don't think so.  Are they just saying, "Take the Fourier series of $h(t)$?"

My second problem is, I'm not familiar with any sort of Fourier series where we take the limit as $T\to \infty.$  Just a reference for such a thing would suffice, I think.

Third, having shown $c\geq 1$, how does that get us from $|P|^2 - n \geq -c$ to $\inf |P| \leq \sqrt{n-1}$.

Comment: Do you assume $\alpha_j\in[0,2\pi)$? Otherwise taking $\alpha_j=2\pi j$ results in $P(t)=n>\sqrt{n-1}$.

Comment: @A.G. No.  The $t$ takes care of that problem.  It's the inf (over $t$) that's supposed to be $\leq \sqrt{n-1}.$

Answer (score 1):

1. Among $\alpha_i-\alpha_j$ there could be same numbers. I think that $\delta_k$'s denote *different* numbers in the set $\{\alpha_i-\alpha_j\}$. Therefore, $b_k$ is exactly the number of repetition of each $\delta_k$ in the set.
2. No need to go for Fourier transforms etc. It is simple integration:
   calculate 
   $$
   \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T\cos\alpha t\cdot\cos\beta t\,dt
   $$
   when $\alpha\ne\beta$ and when $\alpha=\beta$ and then look what happens when $T\to+\infty$. You will see that cosines with different frequencies are kind of "orthonormal" in this sense.
3. Since $-c$ can be any lower bound for $w$, we can take it to be the *exact* lower bound, i.e. $-c=\inf(|P|^2-n)$. It makes 
   $$
   \inf|P|^2=n-c\le n-1.
   $$

Comment: Thanks.  For 1., that was my first thought, but then what accounts for the $c$ in the definition of $h(t)$?  $w(t)$ is the sum of all such cosines, then we add $c$ and somehow end up with the sum of some cosines.  For 2., yes, I think I can make the integrals work out as you say.  For 3., yep.

Comment: @B.Goddard $w$ is the sum of all cosines with nonzero frequencies $\delta_k$. We need this to say that the mean value of $w$ is zero (in the estimation $...=c$). However, the constant $c$ can also be written as cosine with zero frequency, so $h$ is the sum of cosines again where we added $\delta_k=0$. We need to add $c$ to $w$ to make $h(t)\ge 0$ for the inequality ($\int...\le\int...$) to be valid.